# VBA Code crashes PPT Application - unclear reason

Tags: vba, crash, powerpoint

I have a problem with the following Code. What happens is that my PPT application crashes while running the code. It does not always happen and it happens in different parts of the code.

I tried the application.wait-method, but it did not work.

help is appreciated since I am already working on this for days -.-. Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Public myfilename As String

Sub filepicker()
Dim i As Variant
    MsgBox ("In the following dialog please choose the current file")
    Dim myfilenamepicker As FileDialog
    Set myfilenamepicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    myfilenamepicker.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Test PPT"
    myfilenamepicker.Show
    If myfilenamepicker.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        myfilename = myfilenamepicker.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Sub


Sub Saveas_PPT_and_PDF()

Dim PP As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sh As Variant
Dim company, strPOTX, strPfad, pptVorlage, newpath, newpathpdf As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim pptApp As Object

    Call filepicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' set the dropdown from which the company Is Selected
    Set DropDown.ws_company = Tabelle2

    ' the company is the value selected in the dropdown, stored in "C2"
    company = DropDown.ws_company.Range("C2").Value

    On Error Resume Next
        Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
        On Error Resume Next

        If pptApp Is Nothing Then
            Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'loop through the companies in the dropdown menu
    For Each Cell In DropDown.ws_company.Range(DropDown.ws_company.Cells(5, 3), _
                DropDown.ws_company.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        DropDown.ws_company.Range("C2") = Cell

        pptVorlage = myfilename
        Debug.Print (myfilename)

        Set PP = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptVorlage)

        newpath = Replace(myfilename, "AXO", "" & Cell & " AXO")

        PP.UpdateLinks
        PP.SaveAs newpath

        newpathpdf = Replace(newpath, "pptx", "pdf")
        Debug.Print (newpathpdf)
        PP.ExportAsFixedFormat "" & newpathpdf & "", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint

        pptApp.Presentations(newpath).Close

        Set PP = Nothing
    Next

    ' this part below closes PPT application if there are no other presentation
    ' object open. If there is at least 1, it leaves it open
    If IsAppRunning("PowerPoint.Application") Then
        If pptApp.Windows.Count = 0 Then
            pptApp.Quit
        End If
    End If
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    Set PP = Nothing

End Sub

Function IsAppRunning(ByVal sAppName) As Boolean
Dim oApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, sAppName)
    If Not oApp Is Nothing Then
        Set oApp = Nothing
        IsAppRunning = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Note: `Dim company, strPOTX, strPfad, pptVorlage, newpath, newpathpdf As String` creates only one string variable and 5 variants (the `As` applies only to the variable directly before it, not to the whole list).

Comment: You should improve the formatting of your code so it will be better readable and easier to spot errors and typos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong but I can give you a strategy for debugging.

You will want to test all major manipulations seperately. You will want to run each test in the debugger and have screenupdating on so you can see what happens:

- test the filepicker
- test GetObject/CreateObject - do you really need it? You already have PowrPoint open it seems;
- test your loop with a single hardcoded value. What happens with the focus when opening a presentation?
- try without UpdateLinks; try without SaveAs and try without Export (i.e. just open a presentation and close it again).
- check if the presentation really closes, otherwise you might end up with lots of open presentations.
- test closing the application
- test reading from a dropdown box
- test the `IsAppRunning` function. Note that it sets `On Error Resume Next` but does not reset it. Note it does not set `IsAppRunning = False` anywhere.
- try relevant parts of the above in a loop with and without debugging to see what happens and see if it crashes - there could be a timing problem in the Office application, e.g. trying to manipulate a presentation while it is not yet fully loaded.

Minimising your code can help isolate the area that causes the problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and give my the recommendations

1. I tried just opening and closing the presentaiton (without UpdateLinks; try without SaveAs and try without Export) --> Runs pretty often but in the end also crashed

2. The presentation really closes. I have a loop that counts the number of presentations

3. What do you mean by "test reading from a dropdown box"?

4. I will try without "IsAppRunning". Regarding the "IsAppRunning = False" do you think a "...else IsAppRunning = False" is enough?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Ad 3: I mean test if you get the value from the dropdown box; 4: yes, that would be enough (as now all control paths set a value).